# Are Cloud Functions in Firebase Spark plan on the same infrastructure as the Blaze plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been reading other people's experiences of cold starts and general GCF performance and have experienced some rather large load times myself (over 15s in some cases).

I've discovered the number one culprit is having a large number of dependencies on cold boot, so I'll be investigating this in depth next.

However, my question is given an identical GCF am I likely to experience any improvements in latency, cold starts etc on the Spark plan (free) versus the paid Blaze plan?

If they are on different server farms, then wouldn't this mean different dependencies in the cache and thus differing results in performance?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in required cold start time based on billing plan in Cloud Functions.